# Gridview: RowHeaderColumn HyperLinkedField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to use RowHeaderColumn on a HyperLinkField as opposed to a BoundField?

Thanks

Barry

Answer (score 1):

You can use TemplateField of gridview to customize your header

```
 <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="testc1,testc2,testc3">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <a href="#">Link Header Text Here</a>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("testc1") %> --Your Column Data
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="testc2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="testc3"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Cheers,
Lance